# Parsing string given by: #parameter1~value1#parameter2~value2#parameter3

Tags: c++, regex, parsing

Could someone give me some hints on what is the best/elegant approach to extract parameter name and parameter value from a variable length input string? I need to extract those values in order to write them down in another .txt file. Should I use regex? What would be the way to use them?

I know how to do this but using for loops and various if-then conditions and it's a mess. The thing I need is where to look to find some built-in functions that can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: use two split one with # and one with ~ on each result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex is unnecessary overhead in this case. A single-character [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) is enough to do this job. Assuming each parameter (even the first) begins with `#`, the value is optional (default is `""`) and the trailing `#` is always omitted you can do something as:

```
std::string pstr = ...; // the parameter string

typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> Param;
std::vector<Param> params;

std::size_t pos = pstr.find('#');
std::size_t next = pstr.find('#', pos);

while (pos != std::string::npos) {
    std::string param, value;

    std::size_t sep_pos = pstr.find('~', next);
    if (sep_pos != std::string::npos) {
        value = pstr.substr(sep_pos + 1, next - sep_pos - 1);
        param = pstr.substr(pos + 1, sep_pos - pos - 1);
    } else {
        param = pstr.substr(pos + 1, next - pos - 1);
    }
    params.push_back(Param(param, value));
}
```

Note, that [`std::strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok) is a bad suggestion. That function is unsafe and should never be used in normal C++ code.

Comment: Thanks jons34yp for your answer. It really helped me to solve my problem. Cheers!

Comment: @nitish712: It's non-reentrant (i.e. not usable in multi-threaded programs) and modifies the given string (i.e. not usable with const qualified data).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the initial text stored is as follows:

```
param1:value1;param2:value2;param3:value3.....
```

The best way is to use `StringTokenizer` of `java`.
The code looks as follows:

```
StringTokenizer sT=new StringTokenizer(InputString, ";");
while(sT.hasMoreTokens())
{
    String Pair=sT.nextToken();
    String sT2=new StringTokenizer(Pair, ":");
    String param=sT2.nextToken();
    String value=sT2.nextToken();
    System.out.println(param+" "+value);
}
```

On the other hand if, you want to code strictly in `C++`, then you can use the c++ counter part,
`strtok` function. For more see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)